# White screen in expo when another file is being imported to app.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

This is the app.js file, which has no error in it. But when AbcdPage is being imported from AbcdPage.js file the entire simulator & emulator goes entirely white. Nothing is being displayed also terminal in vscode doesn't show any error or warnings.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AbcdPage from "./components/AbcdPage"

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AbcdPage />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here goes AbcdPage.js file, all imports are done correctly in this AbcdPage.js file.

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function AbcdPage(props) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerPosition="right"
          drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
        >
          <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={Screen1} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to your View component style `flex:1`

Comment: This worked, but all the icons in the app just got removed, any solution to that?